# Ngspice postprocessing

Tags: ngspice

As far as simulation goes, I can handle ngspice interactive simulator to validate an design. 
But there are cases where I need to format the plot, chart or whatever is required by a design report.
So, what is the comunity using for post-procesing ngspice results, and what output format to use, how to import the data?

Comment: CTRL-ALT_Print_Scrn --> Paint (then crop/resize) then select all and CTRL_C --> word processor (for images). On a more direct note, you are asking for opinions on what is basically a shaky EE question so you might get this question closed.

Comment: Was expecting a more thenical answer, but eeh, yours is fine too. Good day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options for plotting from inside ngspice (especially version ngspice-35), see [ngspice manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html) chapter 18:

- Internal plotting (native MS Windows or X11 on Linux, Cygwin, macOS) with many options to select UNICODE fonts, colors etc.
- Creating a Postscript output file, then use gv or ghostscript for plotting
- Creating an SVG file, then use a browser, feh or other compatible plot program
- Plotting with Gnuplot

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

There are several [third partyinterfaces](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/resources.html)  that can help you manipulate waveforms.
I saw that [EasyEDA](https://docs.easyeda.com/en/Simulation/Spice-Simulation/index.html) claims:

> Once saved in a Project, a WaveForm window can be exported as a .pdf, .png or .svg file into your browser window. This can then be saved to your device so it is easy to create professional quality documentation.

Searching internet on "ngspice waveform viewer" I found: [post-simulation data processing with Qucs-S and Octave](https://qucs-help.readthedocs.io/en/spice4qucs/PostSim.html)

Comment: Hi. I get some hate for what I asked. I know both links, and almost all 3rd party post porcessing tools available. I just asked for an opinion of which is easier to use, or more capable of those options, if I am wrong to use 3rd party options and the ngspice and nutmeg have what I am looking for and I am just dumb to ask.

Comment: 1) Your question didn't mention you already know all 3rd party tools already. Please do mention it next time. The more specific the question, the less 'useless' answers you get. 2) [Questions asking for opinions will be closed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Like Andy aka already mentioned as well.

Comment: Maybe you should try the ngspice fora (if you haven't that tried that already)

Comment: I understand the rules, it is an opinion question. I did not specified what I know because I found my information scattered around stack exchange, so I tried to ask an general question, to improve what I know and help anyone else in the same position as I am. Sorry.